# How to make extbase extension recognize storage page from plugin?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

In an extbase extension built with extension builder on TYPO3 6.1.7, I haven't set any storagePid via Typoscript.

But I have set the "Record Storage Page" in the plugin:

[image]

I would expect that it would now only fetch records from this page.
But it doesn't, it just returns all items from that table.

How do I make the extension recognize the setting from the plugin?
Or (if it's supposed to do that out of the box) how do I find out why it doesn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following code to your repository

```
namespace <Vendor>\<Extkey>\Domain\Repository;

class ExampleRepository extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Repository {

    // Example for repository wide settings
    public function initializeObject() {
        /** @var $defaultQuerySettings \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Typo3QuerySettings */
        $defaultQuerySettings = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\Typo3QuerySettings');
        // add the pid constraint
        $defaultQuerySettings->setRespectStoragePage(TRUE);
}

    // Example for a function setup changing query settings
    public function findSomething() {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        // add the pid constraint
        $query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(TRUE);
        // the same functions as shown in initializeObject can be applied.
        return $query->execute();
    }
}
```

You will find more informations at this page 
http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/Default_Orderings_and_Query_Settings_in_Repository

Comment: Thanks Stefano! I think I had some messed up settings in my page tree, recreating the whole page anew helped, even without setRespectStoragePage(TRUE). I think I've understood correctly, please correct me if not: the storage page should be respected by default; your code is just to enforce it?

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the settings class (typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Typo3QuerySettings.php) this should be the default. Somehow (some extensions changes it) you need to set it explicitly for your repositories.

`protected $respectStoragePage = TRUE;`

Answer (score 17):

I did a lot of research when my extension's frontend plugin (TYPO3 7.6.4) refused to use the 'pages' field of the plugin ("Record Storage Page"), so I would like to share my findings:

My extension's name is 'tx_dhsnews', my plugin's name is 'infobox'

1. setRespectStoragePage must be set to true (default): $query->setRespectStoragePage(TRUE)
2. In the typoscript-setup, **the plugin-specific storagePid** plugin.tx_dhsnews_infobox.persistence.storagePid **MUST NOT be present at all! Not even with an empty value! Else the 'pages'-field will not be respected!**

That's all. The Extensions Builder just created a typoscript-setup with the storagePid for the specific plugin 'infobox' set to nothing. That resulted in the plugin not respecting the 'pages' - field.

It's no problem to set the storagePid on extension-level (e.g. 'tx_dhsnews..persistence.storagePid'), the value will be merged with the value(s) given in 'pages' ("Record Storage Page"), but as soon the plugin-specific tx_[extension]_[plugin].persistence.storagePid exists in the typoscript, it will overrule everything else!

Hope this will help somebody to save some time + nerves

Comment: Yes, deleting that `persistence.storagePid` line really did save me some nerves, thanks :D

Comment: Soo good to know! Still the same behaviour in TYPO3 8. BUT I found a big downside of this. If you don't define a StoragePage in the plugin, the plugin will find nothing! So no default or at least "give me all" behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I actually modified my MVC controller to achieve a record filtering depending on the actual page(storagePid==page.id).. looked like this:

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;

class MyMVCController extends ActionController {
protected function initializeAction() {
    parent::initializeAction();
    //fallback to current pid if no storagePid is defined
    $configuration = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK);
    if (empty($configuration['persistence']['storagePid'])) {
        $currentPid['persistence']['storagePid'] = GeneralUtility::_GP('id');
        $this->configurationManager->setConfiguration(array_merge($configuration, $currentPid));
    }
[..]
```

I used the solution by [http://wiki.t3easy.de/](http://wiki.t3easy.de:8008/extbase-und-fluid/storagepid-fallback-auf-aktuelle-seite/) and modified the value of the storagePid cause i developed a backend module.
His tscript example didnt worked for me..
Also an [article by Thomas Deuling](http://thomas.deuling.org/de/2012/06/deutsch-die-verwendeted-typo3-storage-id-in-einer-extbase-controller-action-verwenden/) was interesting for the topic..

but i still dont get the whole connection into my mind.. wanna go back to symfony xD

edit: for the modification of the repo queries also this article looked interesting:
https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/Default_Orderings_and_Query_Settings_in_Repository